# Java calendar get previous 10 days from today and set time to 12:00 fails

Tags: java, android, date

I would like to get the 10 days before today and also set the time to 12:00 midnight

I have figured out that a day has 24 hours so 10 days will have 240 hours so I have

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) - 240);
```

The above works but now when I want to set the time to 12:00

I have tried

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
```

After adding the above the 10 days before are now reset to today.

What could be wrong?

Comment: `12:00` usually indicates noon, not midnight. I suggest using 24-hour clock when discussing date-time programming, or anytime accuracy & clarity is paramount.

Comment: Beware: Days not always start at 00:00:00.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [java.time](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary.html) library it can be more easier, you can use :

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.now().minusDays(10),
        LocalTime.of(12, 0)
);
```

---

For example :

Now it is :

```
2018-04-01T13:30
```

Before 10 days, at 12 it return :

```
2018-03-22T12:00
```

Comment: On Android [`LocalDateTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) requires API26 (Android 8). Therefore it is currently not a real option.

Comment: Thank you @Robert new information for me, I don't know about this before, I'm not so familiar with android, but I'm with java.time

Comment: The `LocalDateTime` class is the wrong class for this purpose. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, it ignores real-world anomalies such as Daylight Saving Times (DST).

Comment: @Robert You can use `LocalDateTime` and the other `java.time` classes on API levels lower than 26. See [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) and [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49603483/5772882).

Answer (score 1):

You use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html and method `set` have this behaviour

> set(f, value) changes calendar field f to value. In addition, it sets
>   an internal member variable to indicate that calendar field f has been
>   changed. Although calendar field f is changed immediately, the
>   calendar's time value in milliseconds is not recomputed until the next
>   call to get(), getTime(), getTimeInMillis(), add(), or roll() is made.
>   Thus, multiple calls to set() do not trigger multiple, unnecessary
>   computations. As a result of changing a calendar field using set(),
>   other calendar fields may also change, depending on the calendar
>   field, the calendar field value, and the calendar system. In addition,
>   get(f) will not necessarily return value set by the call to the set
>   method after the calendar fields have been recomputed. The specifics
>   are determined by the concrete calendar class.
>
> Example: Consider a GregorianCalendar originally set to August 31,
>   1999. Calling set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SEPTEMBER) sets the date to September 31, 1999. This is a temporary internal representation that
>   resolves to October 1, 1999 if getTime()is then called. However, a
>   call to set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30) before the call to getTime()
>   sets the date to September 30, 1999, since no recomputation occurs
>   after set() itself.

You call `set` three times and result is last `set` time. So for you purposes you need to use method `add` after(with) `set`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now(                   // Capture the current moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )  // Specify a time zone using proper name, `continent/region`, never 3-4 pseudo-codes such as `PST`, `EST`, `IST`. 
)
.minusDays( 10 )                     // Go back in time ten days, adjusting for time-of-day as need be.
.toLocalDate()                       // Extract a date-only value.
.atStartOfDay(                       // Determine the first moment of that date in a certain time zone. Not always 00:00:00.
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )  
)
.toString()                          // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-03-23T00:00+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

## Avoid legacy date-time classes.

You are using troublesome old date-time classes supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

## java.time

Instead of `Calendar`, use `ZonedDateTime` to represent a moment on the timeline with a wall-clock time used by people of a certain region (time zone).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current moment.
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current moment.
```

## Math

Specify a span of time unattached to the timeline of years-months-days using `Period`.

```
Period p = Period.ofDays( 10 ) ;
```

Go back in time. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) are handled automatically, adjusting time-of-day as need be.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtTenDaysAgo = zdt.minus( p ) ;
```

“Midnight” is a trick concept, ambiguous and amorphous. Instead, focus on the idea of “first moment of the day”.

Always let *java.time* determine the first moment. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as DST mean the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00. To get that first moment, extract a date-only `LocalDate` object. Specify a time zone to determine when that date began in that place.

```
LocalDate ldTenDaysAgo = zdtTenDaysAgo.toLocalDate() ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTenDaysAgoStartOfDay = ldTenDaysAgo.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

If you want to view the same moment as UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdtTenDaysAgoStartOfDay.toInstant() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To add or subtract, you should use the `add` method :

```
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -240);
```

But beware of that, because a day is not always the same as 24 hours, due to Daylight Saving Time effects: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/transition.html

Anyway, Calendar is a very bugged class and it's better to use java.time classes (API level 26), or threetenbp if java.time is not available: http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/

See here how to configure in Android: [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

To consider DST effects, use a ZonedDateTime:

```
// current date/time 
ZonedDateTime.now()
    // minus 10 days
   .minusDays(10)
    // set time to midnight 
   .with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
```

This will take care of the complicated details of DST, including the cases where DST starts at midnight and the day actually starts at 1am - the time is automatically adjusted.

It's not clear if you want midnight (00:00) or noon (12:00). Anyway, if you want noon, just use `LocalTime.NOON`.